# Preloading a multiple select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

So I have a form on a webpage that is a multiple select option input eg.

```
<option name="testData" multiple="multiple">
  <select value="1">Option 1</select>
  <select value="2">Option 2</select>
  <select value="3">Option 3</select>
  <select value="4">Option 4</select>
  <select value="5">Option 5</select>
 </option>
```

Once the form is submitted the selected options are stored within an array (eg. 1,2,3)

The issue is that if I revisit the page I want the data to be split back into individual values and to make sure if they were previously selected they are once again selected.

So in this instance the values 1,2,3 would be already selected within the select menu.

The information is stored in a database and is pulling in correctly. What I am asking is how to take the value (1,2,3 etc.) and identify each as a selected option in the option list. The user can then amend as required.

If possible can this be done with jquery? Javascript would also be ok.

Let me know if this needs a little more explaining and I will do my best to answer any queries

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its should be `<select name="testData" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option ></select>` and use `.val()` to set the value like `$('[name="testData"]').val([1,2,3])`

Comment: The only issue is that the value may not always be 1,2,3 it could be a different value each time, for example 1,2,5 or even 1,3,4,5

But it will always be a value found within the option list

Comment: you can make an ajax call to get array of values

Comment: That doesn't matter, You need to pass the selected value as an array

Comment: @AlexandruMihai how would I do this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Satpal I've made this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfrvwf3f/) with your code, it doesn't work. Can you post a working one?

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst please include jquery library for Satpal solution

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst https://jsfiddle.net/rfrvwf3f/1/

Comment: @AlexandruMihai yours works, indeed I forgot to include JQuery library. Beginners mistake :s. Thank you both Satpal and AlexandruMihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to store the array of selected options into the session storage (if you want to avoid an AJAX call, it will make your script faster)

```
// When your user clicks on the submit button
$( "#id_of_your_submit_btn" ).click(function() {
  // store the selected options into the sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem('my_array_of_selected_values', array_of_selected_options);
});
```

Then when your page will be reloaded you can check wether this sessionStorage is set and then select dynamically the options previously selected (as Alexandru proposed)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var selected_options = sessionStorage.getItem('my_array_of_selected_values');
    if(selected_options) {
       // if something is set into this sessionStorage variable
       // we select the options dynamically
       $("[name='testData']").val(selected_options);
    }

});
```

**NB** : check that the browsers targeted are supported https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Thanks I think this could work, just to check what would go into 'my_array_of_selected_values'? Would this just be the name of the select list? eg. 'testData'

Sorry for the stupid questions!

Comment: No worries, `'my_array_of_selected_values'` is the name of the sessionStorage variable. `testData`is the name of your option HTML tag. the variable `array_of_selected_options` should be set with your array `[1,2,3]` Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$("[name='testData']").val([1,2,3]);
```

or

```
$("select").val([1,2,3]);
```